# How to read specific worksheet using OPCPackage POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Suppose I have a xlsx file consisting of three worksheets. Using this code snippet I'm able to read the whole xlsx file i.e. all three worksheets in which each row is separated by brackets and each cell separated by comma.

```
public static List<List<String>> excelProcess(File xlsxFile) throws Exception {
    int minColumns = -1;
    // The package open is instantaneous, as it should be.
    OPCPackage p = OPCPackage.open(xlsxFile.getPath(), PackageAccess.READ);
    XLSXParse xlsx2csv = new XLSXParse(p, System.out, minColumns);
    xlsx2csv.process();
    System.out.println("row list===="+xlsx2csv.getRowList().size());
    return xlsx2csv.getRowList();
}
```

Here xlsxFile is the path of xlsx file. But I only want the data of a specific worksheet, say worksheet2 so I would pass worksheet name also like below.

```
public static List<List<String>> excelProcess(File xlsxFile,String sheetName) throws Exception {
```

Here sheetName is particular Worksheet's name.

Comment: what is the class `XLSXParse`? I think it is not part of Apache POI and reading the worksheets is happening in there.

Comment: wait.. give me 5 mints..

Comment: Yeh, u were right. XLSXParse is a class. I think that i can do it now. Let me try now. Thanx for response..

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be using any built-in Apache POI code for your parsing, so you'll need to switch to using POI directly!

Once you have, if you look at the methods on [Workbook](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html), you'll see there are methods to let you fetch a given Sheet [by name](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getSheet(java.lang.String)) or [by index](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getSheetAt(int))

Your code would then look something like

```
public static List<List<String>> excelProcess(File xlsxFile, String sheetName) 
              throws Exception {
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(xlsxFile);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName);

    // process sheet contents here

    // eg something like
    DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
    for (Row r : sheet) {
       for (Cell c : r) {
          System.out.println(formatter.formatCellValue(c));
       }
    }
}
```

See the [Usermodel documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api) and [iterating over rows and cells documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) to get started on processing the file with Apache POI